# Azure Python flask App - AD authentication issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, adal

This could be a little complicated to explain, so will do my best.

**Current Solution**

I have a python flask app, which will be deployed to an App Service within Azure. I want the user to login to the app service Via Azure AD authentication. To do this i am using the ADAL library, as i found some code which works to do this.

I have registered the application against Azure AD in order to get the App ID and the App Secret. To do this, i used this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-redirect-uris-to-your-application

app.py

```
import os
import urllib.parse
import uuid

import adal
import flask
import requests

import config
import logging

os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1' # enable non-HTTPS for testing

APP = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='static/templates')
APP.debug = True
APP.secret_key = 'development'
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

SESSION = requests.Session()

@APP.route('/')
def homepage():
    """Render the home page."""
    logging.info('test')
    logger.debug("test1")
    return flask.render_template('homepage.html', sample='ADAL')

@APP.route('/login')
def login():
    """Prompt user to authenticate."""
    auth_state = str(uuid.uuid4())
    SESSION.auth_state = auth_state

    # For this sample, the user selects an account to authenticate. Change
    # this value to 'none' for "silent SSO" behavior, and if the user is
    # already authenticated they won't need to re-authenticate.
    prompt_behavior = 'select_account'

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'response_type': 'code',
                                     'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID,
                                     'redirect_uri': config.REDIRECT_URI,
                                     'state': auth_state,
                                     'resource': config.RESOURCE,
                                     'prompt': prompt_behavior})

    return flask.redirect(config.AUTHORITY_URL + '/oauth2/authorize?' + params)

@APP.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    """Handler for the application's Redirect Uri."""
    code = flask.request.args['code']
    auth_state = flask.request.args['state']
    if auth_state != SESSION.auth_state:
        raise Exception('state returned to redirect URL does not match!')
    auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext(config.AUTHORITY_URL, api_version=None)
    token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_authorization_code(
        code, config.REDIRECT_URI, config.RESOURCE, config.CLIENT_ID, config.CLIENT_SECRET)
    SESSION.headers.update({'Authorization': f"Bearer {token_response['accessToken']}",
                            'User-Agent': 'adal-sample',
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'SdkVersion': 'sample-python-adal',
                            'return-client-request-id': 'true'})
    return flask.redirect('/graphcall')

@APP.route('/graphcall')
def graphcall():
    """Confirm user authentication by calling Graph and displaying some data."""
    endpoint = config.RESOURCE + config.API_VERSION + '/me'
    http_headers = {'client-request-id': str(uuid.uuid4())}
    graphdata = SESSION.get(endpoint, headers=http_headers, stream=False).json()
    return flask.render_template('graphcall.html',
                                 graphdata=graphdata,
                                 endpoint=endpoint,
                                 sample='ADAL')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run(debug=True)
    APP.run()
```

config.py

```
CLIENT_ID = 'd****************************'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'D******************************'
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5000/login/authorized'

# AUTHORITY_URL ending determines type of account that can be authenticated:
# /organizations = organizational accounts only
# /consumers = MSAs only (Microsoft Accounts - Live.com, Hotmail.com, etc.)
# /common = allow both types of accounts
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'

AUTH_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/token'

RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
API_VERSION = 'v1.0'
SCOPES = ['User.Read'] # Add other scopes/permissions as needed.


# This code can be removed after configuring CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET above.
if 'ENTER_YOUR' in CLIENT_ID or 'ENTER_YOUR' in CLIENT_SECRET:
    print('ERROR: config.py does not contain valid CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET')
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)
```

Currently when logging into the app, i am presented with the login screen, which i can login with, i think am passed to my organisations password screen for the login. After that the application fails to get the bearer token. which then redirects the application back to the home page.

**Questions**

- Is there a way where i dont have to use the Azure AD Authorization for the app service and i can just authorize with Azure AD without it.
- What is the better way to do this.

Or can i authenticate with Azure AD without having to use the ADAL library and use the builtin Azure AD authorization for when logging into my flask app service.

I understand this may not be explained very well, so any questions or more info, please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would rather use builtin Azure AD authentication than ADAL library.

It is very convenient to use builtin Azure AD authentication if you just want to use the sign in feature, you needn't to modify your code. But if you want to get the access token, you need to collect it yourself.

**How to get the access token?**

From your server code, the provider-specific tokens are injected into the [request header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code), so you can easily access them.

> App Service provides a built-in [token store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#token-store), which is a
>   repository of tokens that are associated with the users of your web
>   apps, but you must write code to collect, store, and refresh these
>   tokens in your application.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Hello @Caiyi, If i use the the Azure AD authentication method, can i still use the access token once authenticated to query the Azure graph API to get user information. Thanks

Comment: @harry4912 Yes, you can. See the update in the answer. You can also get the user claims in the request header. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims