# oauth2session dynamics365 : keep receiving Error 401 Unatuthorized

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

## The use case

I am trying to connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 - Field Service.

I am using Python, Falsk and OAuth2Session to perform a Oauth2 authentication

I have setup the Azure App on Azure.

## the error message

I keep receiving the HTTP Error 401

Who could help me?

## the code : config.py

```py
"""Configuration settings for running the Python auth samples locally.

In a production deployment, this information should be saved in a database or
other secure storage mechanism.
"""

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

CLIENT_ID = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_application_client_id"]
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_client_secrets"]
REDIRECT_URI = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_redirect_path"]

# AUTHORITY_URL ending determines type of account that can be authenticated:
# /organizations = organizational accounts only
# /consumers = MSAs only (Microsoft Accounts - Live.com, Hotmail.com, etc.)
# /common = allow both types of accounts

AUTHORITY_URL = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_authority"]
AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_authorization_base_url"]
TOKEN_URL = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_token_url"]

AUTH_ENDPOINT = "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"


RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
API_VERSION = os.environ["dynamics365_field_service_version"]
SCOPES = [
    "https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation"
]




#     "https://dynamics.microsoft.com/business-central/overview/user_impersonation",
#     "https://graph.microsoft.com/email",
#     "https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access",
#     "https://graph.microsoft.com/openid",
#     "https://graph.microsoft.com/profile",
#     "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
#     "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All"
# ]  # Add other scopes/permissions as needed.
```

## the code : dynamics365_flask_oauth2.py

```py
# *-* coding:utf-8 *-*

# See https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session, url_for
from flask.json import jsonify
import os

import flaskr.library.dynamics365.field_service.config as config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

# This information is obtained upon registration of a new dynamics
# client_id = "<your client key>"
# client_secret = "<your client secret>"
# authorization_base_url = 'https://dynamics.com/login/oauth/authorize'
# token_url = 'https://dynamics.com/login/oauth/access_token'


@app.route("/")
def index():
    """Step 1: User Authorization.

    Redirect the user/resource owner to the OAuth provider (i.e. dynamics)
    using an URL with a few key OAuth parameters.
    """
    dynamics = OAuth2Session(
        config.CLIENT_ID, scope=config.SCOPES, redirect_uri=config.REDIRECT_URI
    )
    authorization_url, state = dynamics.authorization_url(config.AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL)

    # State is used to prevent CSRF, keep this for later.
    session["oauth_state"] = state

    print(f"Please go here and authorize : {authorization_url}")
    return redirect(authorization_url)


# Step 2: User authorization, this happens on the provider.


@app.route("/login/authorized", methods=["GET"])  # callback
def callback():
    """ Step 3: Retrieving an access token.

    The user has been redirected back from the provider to your registered
    callback URL. With this redirection comes an authorization code included
    in the redirect URL. We will use that to obtain an access token.
    """

    if session.get("oauth_state") is None:
        return redirect(url_for(".index"))

    dynamics = OAuth2Session(
        config.CLIENT_ID, state=session["oauth_state"], redirect_uri=config.REDIRECT_URI
    )

    token = dynamics.fetch_token(
        token_url=config.TOKEN_URL,
        client_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization_response=request.url,
    )
    print(f"token: {token}")
    # At this point you can fetch protected resources but lets save
    # the token and show how this is done from a persisted token
    # in /profile.
    session["oauth_token"] = token

    # return redirect(url_for(".dynamics_get_accounts_postman"))

    return redirect(url_for(".dynamics_get_accounts"))


@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET"])
def profile():
    """Fetching a protected resource using an OAuth 2 token.
    """
    dynamics = OAuth2Session(config.CLIENT_ID, token=session["oauth_token"])
    return jsonify(dynamics.get("https://api.dynamics.com/user").json())


@app.route("/get_accounts")
def dynamics_get_accounts():

    if session.get("oauth_token") is None:
        return redirect(url_for(".index"))

    dynamics = OAuth2Session(
        client_id=config.CLIENT_ID,
        # token="Bearer " + session["oauth_token"]["access_token"]
        token=session["oauth_token"],
    )

    result = dynamics.get("https://{env_name}.{region}.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0")

    if result.status_code != 200:
        result = {"status code": result.status_code, "reason": result.reason}
    else:
        result = result.json()

    result = jsonify(result)
    return result


import requests


@app.route("/dynamics_get_accounts_postman")
def dynamics_get_accounts_postman():

    if session.get("oauth_token") is None:

        return redirect(url_for(".index"))

    url = "https://{env_name}.{region}.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts"

    payload = {}
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
        "OData-Version": "4.0",
        "If-None-Match": "null",
        "Authorization": f'Bearer {session["oauth_token"]["access_token"]}',
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    result = response.text.encode("utf8")
    print(f"result : {result}")

    return jsonify(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This allows us to use a plain HTTP callback
    os.environ["DEBUG"] = "1"

    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: are you able to test with postman ?

Comment: What is the `TOKEN_URL`? Is it `'https://dynamics.com/login/oauth/access_token'`? The AAD token endpoint should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`. I'm not sure how you implement `dynamics.fetch_token`. But you can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808323/azure-python-flask-app-ad-authentication-issue. Besides, if you can capture the full request of getting token and share it, it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi any updates on this issue?

Comment: The answer is this: I missed the parameter 'resource' in the query string

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `resource`was missing when generating the `authorization_url`.

```py
    authorization_url, state = dynamics.authorization_url(
        config.AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL + f"?resource={config.DYNAMICS365_CRM_ORG}"
    )
```